# How do I tell CUPS to not leave white space in the margins?

Tags: cups, label-printer

I have a Brother QL-560 (rumored to behave like a 570), using the "ptouch" back-end driver, version 1.4.2, with CUPS 2.2.1.

My problem is that I need to print+cut labels which are exactly N mm high (the size is variable, I pass a custom paper size to each job), with (almost) no margins. Cutting works and the labels have the correct height, but the rasterizer refuses to paint a couple of millimeters on the top and bottom of the label. CUPS also adds some space to the bottom, thus the label is too large.

How do I teach CUPS to not do that? I don't particularly want to write a program that directly talks to the printer …

Comment: There might be information useful to you in [How to set the minimum margin in CUPS / foomatic driver?](https://superuser.com/q/1026576/272824)

Comment: There isn't unfortunately. I cannot modify the PPD because the label height is variable. That's why the printer is equipped with a cutter …